# git commit doesn't add files to xcodeproj

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, git

I am having issues where some assets in my xcode projec (ttf's, xib, images) are not added to my project when I do a pull from some other computer. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Are they added to the project on the remote? Xcode requires that you add files to the project explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some bad advice floating around out there that suggests you should add your `.xcodeproj` to your gitignore.  This is one of the problems it causes.  If you have done this, then you should remove it from your gitignore and check your `.xcodeproj` bundle into Git.

Answer (score 0):

The machine which is ignoring the files may have been configured to ignore certain files.

Check the value of `core.excludesfile` in your `gitconfig` by runnning `git config -l`. The value should be the path to a file with a list of files to ignore--check to make sure you aren't ignoring any of the files you listed in your original question, and remove them if you are.

[Here](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html) is some more information on ignoring files.